# tracert with specific network device

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, traceroute

I use Windows Server 2003 and would like to run a tracert with a specific network device. We have two devices in there, while the first is the default one, which the tracert works with. The other network device would be of interest for me, though, and I would like to accomplish the tracert command with that device.

I tried setting a source address with `-S` but it is not recognized as valid address and I also doubt that this is the way to go.

Any ideas on how to let tracert use a specific device without disabling the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a route for your tracert. tracert uses the Windows routing table. So if you've got two devices (e.g. `if1=192.168.0.1/24` and `if2=192.168.1.1/24`) and want to use the second one, you'd have to set a specific route for the host you want to trace. 
Some details would be nice to answer your question better (**obfuscated** IPs of your NICs, IP / subnet of the host you want to trace, etc.)
Also: the `-S` switch only works for IPv6.

If you know the hosts in your route, you can also try to use `tracert -j hopA hopB hopC [...]`

Comment: Let's go with your if1, if2 examples. I actually am not even interested in the target, it could just be a tracert to stackoverflow.com. There are routers and a company network involved and I just would like to know what hops I encounter on my way out given that both of the network devices go to different slots in the wall (with a different backend, as far as I know)

Comment: How many default routes do you have configured? Do you *know* that you can access every host you want from both interfaces?

Comment: I don't know about the concept of routes at all, I'm afraid. The second network device is accessible from outside, though, so that I strongly assume I can also go out with it.

Comment: Add a route print output to your question. I think you could only be able to test your scenario by switching default gateways, or even not at all.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked specifically for Windows Server 2003, but If you have two network interfaces (i.e. a computer running active internet connections on both Ethernet and Wi-Fi) on more recent versions of Windows (including Windows Server) you can adjust the metric of one interface to prioritize it over the other.  The interface with the lowest metric will take precedence over the other causing the **tracert** to be sent through that interface.

To find out what the metric is of the primary interface (as well as for any other interfaces), open CMD and enter command *route print*.  Whatever the metric is of the primary interface (which usually appears at the very top of the Active Routes: list under the Ipv4 Route Table), go to the change adapter settings of the desired interface with the higher metric and set it to any number lower than the primary interface's metric.

To do this

1. Go to Control panel
2. Select Network and Sharing Center (or select Network and Internet first if in Category View)
3. Select Change Adapter settings
4. Right-click the interface that you want the traceroute to go through, choose properties,
5. Double-click Internet Protocol Version 4 (tcp/ipv4)
6. Choose the advanced button at the bottom
7. Deselect Automatic Metric and set the metric to a number lower than the metric of the primary interface.